# Best approach to distribute a key into multiple tables within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

This is the case. I have a master table with an invoice number (int) and many tables with related data. When a invoice is made I increment the invoice number in the master table and then put the additional data, and the invoice number too, in the rest of the tables.

As everything is in a transaction (READ COMMITED), all changes are not phisically written until the this transaction is commited.

I know I'll have an error if some other transaction uses the same invoice number at the same time and commits first. I could retry with a new number but, is this the best approach ?

If there are many concurrent long invoices (transactions with a lot of data) there could be many many retries.

I'm thinking in a way to reserve an invoice number quickly or locking it but I don´t know how....

Comment: Why not just use an identity? The only caveat would be if you need to guarantee no missing invoice numbers.

Comment: An Identity column and calling Scope_Identity() was not an option?

Comment: No matter what scheme you use, you can get missing sequences if the transaction rolls back. Espcially if other transactions have in meantime been added. Why do you think invoices should never have gaps? I would push this back as a bad requirement personally. It is causing you to create performance and possibly data integrity problem and for no gain at all. What would it mean to the user if there was a gap? Why would this create a problem?

Comment: @HLGEM - Might be a government or statuatory requirement - unique, incrementing, consecutive tax invoice numbers or the like.

Comment: Right !!! It´s a legal requirement !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an auto_incrementing invoice id, your transaction engine should take care of this for you.

I.E. suppose the current highest invoice is 2, you insert a new one by adding a row to that table. Calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give you the ID of the row you just inserted in that master table of invoices, which is 3. If at the same time another another transaction begins, it will get the number 4. Your transaction engine is smart enough to not double assign the ID. You can then use this ID to tag all of your data in the ancillary tables without worrying that it will be doubly assigned.

Comment: Great !! I didn´t knew the engine was so smart, but in an invoice, sequence must be mantained, what if the transaction with number 3 is aborted ? I will loose invoice number 3...

Comment: why must sequence be maintained? there is no valid reason for that generally.

Comment: well, in Argentina at least, the invoice number is sequential and cannot have "holes", unless the invoice is "annulled".

Comment: this is tricky, you can use these potentially non-sequential gap-containing ids as internal ids, and then present the user with an id that is simply the index of that id e.g. if your internal ids were 1,2,4,5   internal id 4 would map to 3 etc... but this would give you briefly inconsistent ids if a later transaction committed before an earlier one...

Comment: not that this solves the problem in the way you want, but if you are adding invoices, this sounds like something fait accompli, is it not just possible to perform all of your checks in this situation before hand and then only get the id once you are sure your transaction is bound to succeed? if there is some sort of dependency, you could insert the data in the side tables with a temporary value and then swap these out for permanent ids once you are sure that the transaction is good to commit.

Comment: mmm ... sometimes it's not "fait accompli", maybe the process of  invoicing checks availability of goods and then commits.

Comment: why not insert all the data with a 'pending' value for the invoice id, once you are sure everything is inserted to your liking and the transaction will commit you then get an id using the process described in the answer and swap out all of the pending values for the actual invoice id and then commit. this would ensure that every id is used and sequential. since you are in a transaction you won't see other pending values outside of your transaction so you don't have to worry about mixing up invoices.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO YourHeaderTable  (col1, col2,..) values (...)---where PK is identity
SELECT @newID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (@newID,...)  --use the @newID from YourHeaderTable  
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES (@newID,....) --use the @newID from YourHeaderTable  
...

COMMIT
```

and you will never have a problem with two concurrent users with the same new id.  The database will manage the increment of the ID and concurrent users for you, making this error free and reliable.  Anything you try to do other than this is nor only reinventing the wheel, but will be more complex, less reliable and more prone to error.

Comment: Your solution, and the others before, assume I can use an Identity column, which is no always the case. As I commented before, I cannot leave holes in the invoice sequence. I need a solution without Identities.

Comment: By reading your question, I do not see any mention of that issue.  However, an idenity can still be used.  the row's internal ID does not have to be the same as the value displayed to the user.  use an identity as the PK and FKs to all the children tables. you can then use any value (determined by any method) as an invoice number to display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IDENTITY` column – that will guarantee a unique value. And you can (if you're using SQL Server 2005+) use the `OUTPUT` clause of the initial `INSERT` query to capture the ID value generated for your invoice row(s). If you're inserting multiple invoices you should capture additional columns from your insert to uniquely identify the invoices for inserting related rows in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you absolutely can't have holes (as per identity), then you are going to need to lock your custom id / seed table row until you are 100% sure that all of your inserts have committed. However, you'll also need to make sure any other concurrent accesses to this record are also SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT NextId FROM myKeysTable
WITH (XLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
WHERE myTablePKName = 'SomeId'
...
```

This will hold an exclusive lock on the row, preventing other reads (and with the SERIALIZABLE proviso).

Alternatively, have a look at [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) - with examples [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005). Just ensure that there is only one way to access your custom keys table.

But this doesn't sound very scalable / performant.

Comment: Using application locks is very interesting. I will consider it.